# CORS works on Chrome but not on Safari or on iOS device

Tags: ionic4

CORS works on Chrome but not on Safari or on iOS device (IONIC APP)
i tried to add some headers to my request
but with no use

```
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/json'
```

I also tried to disable CROSS-ORIGIN Restriction in Safari , it worked well but not on IOS simulator or device

So , how to fix it ?

Comment: "i tried to add some headers to my reques"- You need to add this headers to the response, not the request!

Comment: add header on web api or service not in application

Comment: Actually i'm trying not to install any more plugins , so i tried to add every thing every where in a desperate attempt not to install any thing more , but i think i will try native HTTP as @KhurshidAnsari said

Comment: native plugin work perfect because i am using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it by adding `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:"*"` and replacing * by my custom headers in server side Config

Comment: Not working when api is in azure app service

Answer (score 0):

Ionic application(android, ios and ionic serve) work on local host. By default web api not allow request from different origin.

So you have 3 options :

1. Allow cross origin request in web api / server.
2. Setup proxy in ionic application [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuring.html). I tried it worked in android not in ios.
3. Use ionic native http [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) (recommended) it will resolve in both.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following code on your app's backend code.
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i got same problem but i resolve it by using `cordova-plugin-advanced-http` for android and ios device.

**Install**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
npm install @ionic-native/http
```

**Use**

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

constructor(private http: HTTP) {}

...

this.http.get('http://ionic.io', {}, {})
  .then(data => {

    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);

  })
  .catch(error => {

    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.error); // error message as string
    console.log(error.headers);

  });
```

More details: see [official link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http)